# Flutter dynamic checkbox will not change

Tags: flutter

I am dynamically building a CheckboxListTile, it comes up fine but when I click the check box I would get this error

```
The following assertion was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 2730 pos 14:
'_debugUltimatePreviousSiblingOf(after, equals: _firstChild)': is not true.
```

is seemed to be related to duplicate key, so I added a key to my toplevel listview and the error stopped, but now

my list of checkboxes gets built with this code

```
new FutureBuilder(
            future: _getRefDocs(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return new Text('Waiting to start');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return new Text('');
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  } else {
                    //myInitialData = snapshot.data;
                    return new ListView(
                      key: new Key(key['docid'].toString())
                      children: snapshot.data.map((dynamic key) {
                        bool myvalue = false;
                        if (key['selected'] == 1) {
                          myvalue = true;
                          selectdocs.add(key['docid']);
                        }
                        return new CheckboxListTile(
                            title: new Text(key['docname']),
                            value: myvalue,
                            //selected: myvalue,
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                myvalue = value;
                              });

                              if (value == true) {
                                selectdocs.add(key['docid']);
                              } else {
                                selectdocs.remove(key['docid']);
                              }
                            }
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                  }
              }
            });
```

Now however after I added the Key, the keyboard will not pop up, the check box does not change when clicked and when I click it, it bounces back up to the text box focus at the top. If I remove the key, then the error comes back everytime I click the checkbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is the line `selected: myValue` commented out? That's what controls whether or not the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I tried it both ways and it did not change the error or when I get rid of the error by adding key to listview, it still jumps back to the top and the keyboard does not work.  I also added a scrollcontroller and does not help.

Comment: Ok, just checking

Comment: @Robert: Have you found the solution? I am having the same issue.

Comment: It seems that the error is pointing to your `NotificationListener`. I've tried to check you code and can't find where exactly you are calling the [`NotificationListener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html) widget. Would it be possible if you could share your [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed on an update way back as mentioned in this [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19809#issuecomment-408022939). I suggest trying to use the latest version of Flutter SDK and try running it again. If you're still having issues, it'd help if you're able to provide a [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run.